# How do I add query params to pagerfanta paginator with symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, pagerfanta

I'm using [pagerfanta](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle) with symfony 4.
I'm paginating DoctrineORM results with pagerfanta.

I want to paginate search results, without query params it's all working great :

```
{{ pagerfanta(articles, 'twitter_bootstrap4_translated', {routeName: 'articles_paginated'}) }}
```

I have urls looking like this :

```
http://host/articles/page/1
```

How do I add a param in the view so that the generated urls include some parameters, for example :

```
http://host/articles/published/1/page/1
```

Or :

```
http://host/articles/page/1?published=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `routeParams` :

```
    {{ pagerfanta(articles, 'twitter_bootstrap4_translated', 
        {
            'routeName': 'articles_paginated',
            'routeParams': {},
        }
    ) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not see this in the (lacking) documentation. What's the best approach, routeParams or play with the route ?

Comment: I always use my reply :  `routeName` and `routeParams` :)